# navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({audio: true, video: true}) inside docker on gcloud

Tags: docker, puppeteer, gcloud

I'm trying to record the screen with audio of a google meet video call inside docker running on a server and the display media returns either a dom error, or nothing.

I know there's an bug for when trying to use getMediaDevices for chrome/chromium when running in headless, which is why I'm using chrome in headfull mode.

Anyone has any idea on what the problem might be?

Thanks

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:bullseye

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb ffmpeg curl wget gnupg2 apt-utils pulseaudio socat alsa-utils gcc g++ make x264 
    #\ libgles2 libdbus-glib-1-2 libxrandr-dev libxcursor-dev

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get install -y chromium
#RUN chromium-browser --product
RUN whereis chromium

RUN adduser root pulse-access

ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"

RUN mkdir /var/run/dbus
# Moved the lines to run.sh script since the dbus-daemon doens't seem to start when the image loads
# RUN dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id
# RUN dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address

RUN rm -rf /var/run/pulse /var/lib/pulse /root/.config/pulse

COPY run.sh /
RUN chmod +x /run.sh

ENV DISPLAY=:1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/sh echo 'Starting DBus...'

dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address

echo 'DBUS session address ->' $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1 --system --disallow-exit --disallow-module-loading

xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1920x1080x24 -ac -nolisten tcp -dpi 96 +extension RANDR" node assistant-v2.js
```

the part .js code

```
...
const options = {
    headless: true,
    executablePath: env.CHROME_PATH,
    args: [
        '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', // doesn't ask to access the microphone and camera!
        '--disable-web-security',
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--enable-webgl-image-chromium',
        '--start-maximized',
        '--start-fullscreen',
        '--enable-webgl-developer-extensions',
        '--enable-webgl-draft-extensions',
        '--use-gl=egl', // removes de gpu graphics errors???
        //'--use-fake-device-for-media-stream' // shows an ugly video as camera input
    ],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
    devtools: false,
};

await page.evaluate((env) => {
    ...
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: {
            cursor: "never",
            frameRate: parseInt(env.RECORDING_FRAMERATE),
            width: {
                ideal: parseInt(env.RECORDING_WIDTH),
                max: parseInt(env.RECORDING_WIDTH),
            },
            height: {
                ideal: parseInt(env.RECORDING_HEIGHT),
                max: parseInt(env.RECORDING_HEIGHT),
            },
        },
    });
    ...
}, env);
```

Docker logs:

```
Starting DBus...
unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket,guid=2cfd47617e82651c6157cfd26385eeca
DBUS session address -> unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode, forcibly disabling SHM mode.
PAGE_LOG:  [Report Only] This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.
PAGE_LOG:  [Report Only] This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment.
....
Joined meeting!
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Could not start video source
    at ExecutionContext._ExecutionContext_evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:229:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:107:16)
    at async /usr/src/app/assistant-v2.js:246:13
```

If I enable the `'--use-fake-device-for-media-stream'` in puppeteer options, it gets the video stream, but only for the fake device media stream:

Here are the logs with the `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream enabled`:

```
PAGE_LOG:  video track id:  8a4da4d8-ce87-4535-8bf6-0c12b85f353f 
PAGE_LOG:  video track kind:  video 
PAGE_LOG:  video track kind:  screen:-3:0 
PAGE_LOG:  audio track id:  6e68abab-6202-48de-ae5c-05dcd81fe208 
PAGE_LOG:  audio track kind:  audio
```

Comment: If you need a display server, a DBus daemon, an audio server, a browser, _and_ your application, would a virtual machine be a better match than a single-process container?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze. I've considered using a virtual machine, and I can reuse the same docker file to spin up one on google cloud, but that doesn't solve the concurrency issue I still need to account for since each instance is serving a single meeting.

Any idea if the issue would continue if it would run inside a vm?